# Gpu works good only if i reset the pc while attempting to the first boot or in live usb mode

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, display-resolution, amdgpu

[AMD Athlon 64 xp3200] with old [ati rage 128 PRO agp], [xubuntu 18], I have this old machine.

The GPU only runs fine if i reset the pc while attempting to the boot just after the grub menu, i tried to set the grub but the problem persist (used nomodeset removed the quiet splash), i noticed some differences:

- if i normally restart the pc with no splash, the fonts resolution after the grub menu gonna be high
- if i restart the pc and reset the pc while 
  attempting at the first boot (just after the grub menu),later on the second attempt the fonts resolution in splash loading gonna be low or there gonna be a textual splash and the gpu gonna work as aspected...

seems something about the loading of drivers or kerner modules, im not very expert in grub and boot loading, also sorry for my bad explanation in english, any clue or resolution!?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

nomodeset

The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel. So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black screen. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

This way you can boot safely, and then dish out to X the business of selecting the appropriate drive for your needs. You might even decide to do no programming whatsoever, and see whether the simple command

```
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

(this works on Debian and derivatives, which is your case) might do in your case.

EDIT:

it is possible to disable a graphical boot completely. Copy

```
  cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub-orig
```

The edit /etc/default/grub, comment out this line,

```
  #GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

modify this line to look like

```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
```

then uncomment this line,

```
  GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Save, run

```
   update-grub
```

when you reboot,if you do not have a broken installation, you will kind yourself in text mode. After reconfiguring X, youmay start the graphical session with

```
   startx
```